# IExcelDataReader is reading xlsx but not xls files

Tags: c#, excel, dataset, filestream, openfiledialog

I'm new with Excel Data Reader and i have a problem.
My program is reading only .xlsx files and can't read .xls files.
Any help will be appreciated
Here is my code:

```
OpenFileDialog ope = new OpenFileDialog();
            ope.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";

            Invoke((Action)(() => { ope.ShowDialog(); }));
            label2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                label2.Visible = true;
            });

            FileStream stream = new FileStream(ope.FileName, FileMode.Open);
            IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

            string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conna = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            conna.Open();


            foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                {
                    try
                    {

}
}
}
            excelReader.Close();
            stream.Close();
```

Thanks so much!

The Debug when opening xls file:

```
The thread 0xf58 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x2764 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'ProjectExcelv2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectExcelv2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Marios\Desktop\C# Projects\eStatistics\ProjectExcelv2\ProjectExcelv2\bin\Debug\ProjectExcelv2.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ProjectExcelv2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectExcelv2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Marios\Desktop\C# Projects\eStatistics\ProjectExcelv2\ProjectExcelv2\bin\Debug\Excel.4.5.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ProjectExcelv2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectExcelv2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Marios\Desktop\C# Projects\eStatistics\ProjectExcelv2\ProjectExcelv2\bin\Debug\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException' occurred in ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll
'ProjectExcelv2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectExcelv2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ProjectExcelv2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectExcelv2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ProjectExcelv2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectExcelv2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ProjectExcelv2.exe
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages?

Comment: Yes the result object is empty and the message is this:

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ProjectExcelv2.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Please debug your code and identify where the `System.NullReferenceException` occurs.

Answer (score 0):

For .xls files try using:

```
ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream)
```